# adding a key value pair in java hashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map which maps cost with position:

```
Map<Vector<Double>,Double> positionCost=new HashMap<Vector<Double>,Double>();
```

positions are  Vectors of type double.

I am putting cost for each position by:

```
positionCost.put(position, newcost);
```

Now I have a vector where I save all the cost produced `cost.add(newcost);` for all the positions.
But there is one problem - the size of `HashMap` is not equal to the size of vector of costs.

```
System.out.println("no of particles"+" "+cost.size()+positionCost.size());
```

I am not able to figure out why.

Comment: Well the thing is that when u comparing vector size that will give size of vector and hashmap that u getting that is size of all vector that you adding in that. So that won't be equal. Perhaps it could be but that both are separate things. See manual of hashmap

Comment: Why is a "position" a `Vector`? And what is your variable _cost_?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose because it has different coordinates in 4 dimensions and I am representing them as a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the `positionCost` `Map` won't be the same as the size of the cost `Vector` if you are adding the same `position` key more than once to the `Map`. In that case, the latter value associated with that key will overwrite the previous value that was associated that key, and the size of the Map will stay the same.

You should add a condition before adding to the map :

```
if (!positionCost.containsKey(position)) {
    positionCost.put(position, newcost);
} else {
    // the key already exists in the map. It might be a bug, or it might be 
    // a valid situation that you have to decide how to handle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are adding a position-to-cost mapping to your map multiple times for the same position? I.e. the same Vector object? Or perhaps some position objects have the same hashcode? This will mean that you will replace an entry in your map at some point. The Vector object behaves differently - it merely appends the object. So I suggest printing the hashcode of the position object you are using as a key to debug.

Answer (score 0):

This is because size of a hashmap depends on the number of keys.If keys are same,then it will count them as 1.So in your case the hashmap is counting the number of position.Hence the values are different